# Не работает скрипт клик по объекту внутри bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть изображение, по клику на которое должно появляться окно alert.
Изображение находится внутри слайда bx slider. Но по клику ничего не происходит.

```
<div class="blog_slide_2">
     <img id="play" src="img/play.png">
      <video id="movie" src="video/kitten.mp4" controls></video>
</div>
<script>
$('#play').click(function(){
    alert ('алё');
});
</script>
```

Вообще, как полный нуб, пробовала скрипт оборачивать в такие конструкции:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){});
$(document).on('load', function(){});
$(window).on('ready', function(){});
$(window).on('load', function(){});
```

Пробовала делать делегирование события (знаю, бред, ведь контент статический),
но так хотя бы это событие появлялось в списке Event Listeners. Но, по-прежнему, не работало.
Помогите, пoжалуйста, заставить его работать.

Comment: вы ищите элемент `#play`, но в примере его нет

Comment: откуда вы взяли его?

Comment: @ThisMan `<img id='play'>`

Comment: @Настюшка-хрюшка у меня ваш код работает. Вы jquery подключили к странице?

Comment: Также возможно видео перекрывает картинку. Убедитесь что клик происходит именно по картинке

Comment: @ThisMan,  перед отправкой на stackoverflow перенесла этот id на изображение вне слайдера, проверить. Забыла вернуть, так и скопировала сюда код. Сорянский.

Comment: ответ уже есть, похожий на правду, прочитайте, может поможет)

Comment: @stckvrw, да, конечно, другие скрипты и слайдер работают

Comment: этот баг, который наблюдается в хроме, начиная с версии, вроде, 74, клик по элементам внутри bxslider'a не срабатывает, один из вариантов это установить `touchEnabled: false` для слайдера, но тогда не будет работать прокрутка пальцем, есть еще варианты решения тут https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/779

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, спасибо,  Попробовала поставить вместо клика mousedown, вроде работает, touchEnabled не хочется отключать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут `id` должен быть уникальным. Если Вы используете его несколько раз, событие клика сработает только на первом. Лучше добавьте `play`, например, в класс или атрибут `data`

Разметка:

```
<div>
    <div class="box">
        <img class="play" src="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img class="play" src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".play").click(function() {
            alert(1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

В случае, если будете использовать атрибут `data`:

Разметка будет такой:

```
<img data-play src="..." />
```

А скрипт таким:

```
$("[data-play]").click(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Решением оказалось заменить событие click на mousedown, при этом функцию этого клика вложила в функцию слайдера:

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
  $('#play').on ( 'mousedown', function(){
    alert ('Клик по play');
  }
});
```

Потом был интересный момент с pager. Он у меня был стандартный, не кастомный. 
Там я сделала то же самое, но клик по кнопкам пейджера не работал в мобильной версии. Получалось переключить слайд, но  остановить видео, например, не выходило. 
Заработало после того, как вместо mousedown по пейджеру поставила touchend.

```
$('.new').on ( 'touchend', function(){
     //alert ('Клик по пейджеру, видео на паузе');
});
```

Класс $('.new') добавила через опцию Bx-слайдера onSliderLoad:

```
  onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
   $("body > div > div.bx-controls.bx-has-pager > div > div").addClass("new");
  }
```

Спасибо всем, особенно ВадимЛешкевич, за помощь. Надеюсь, мой ответ кому-то ещё пригодиться. Всё заработало!!!

Comment: Совсем забыла, там ещё нужно добавить кое-что в файл jquery.bxslider.js, ответ тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541121/domexception-failed-to-execute-setpointercapture-on-element-and-releasepoin